# jquery find child element is checkbox or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to find whether child node is checkbox or not

```
<div class="dhx_multi_select_userselect" style="overflow: auto; height: 22px; position: relative;">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="1">test</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="2">cartoon</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="3">magic</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="4">ads</label>
</div>

$( "dhx_multi_select_userselect" ).find( "checkbox" ).each()
{
alert('Make');
}
```

but above code is showing alert for 1 time. actually it should popup for 4 times

whats the issue any suggestion to solve problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess problem is the way you used `each` and you missed the `dot` for class selector and colon : before checkbox.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P8ZVd/)**

```
$( ".dhx_multi_select_userselect" ).find( ":checkbox" ).each(function(){    
    alert('Make');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.each()` function is having a syntax error.

Try,

```
$(".dhx_multi_select_userselect" ).find("[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
   alert('Make');
});
```

Comment: @Chintan_chiku Are you having this code wrapped inside a script tag.?

Comment: @Chintan_chiku Both this and Adil's answer should work. You are probably either implementing your code incorrect, or not loading jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
if( $('dhx_multi_select_userselect').find('input[type="checkbox"]') ){
    alert('make')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following and avoid using find method, it will be faster too.

```
$( ".dhx_multi_select_userselect input[type=checkbox]" ).each(function(){    
  alert($(this).parent().text());
});
```